# RMarkdown accessing parameter from bash chunk

Tags: r, bash, r-markdown

I created an RMarkdown file `file.Rmd` with parameters.

I know how to access parameters within a `r chunk` but not from a `bash chunk`

If there is absolutely no way to do so, I will write the parameters in a file through `r chunk` and then read it from `bash chunk`...

````
---
output: html_document
params:
  myParam1:
    label: "Choose 1st parameter"
    value: 20
    input: slider
    min: 0
    max: 100
  myParam2:
    label: "Choose 2nd parameter"
    value: "Hello"
    input: text
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
print(paste("1st parameter :",params$myParam1))
print(paste("2nd parameter :",params$myParam2))
```

```{bash}
# Don't know how to get parameters here
echo $params
```
````

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've seen a few options

1. Use `Sys.setenv` to export variables from [R to bash](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/061-bash-variable.md), so add this line to an R chunk.

   `Sys.setenv(params = params$myParam1)`
2. Use the [runr package](http://rpubs.com/yihui/bash-knitr)

Answer (score 5):

To apply the export-to-envirnoment idea from [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43527155/3780389) to *all* params, just add the following [`do.call`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.0/topics/do.call) loop to an R chunk before the bash chunk:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
for (key in names(params)) {
  do.call('Sys.setenv', params[key])
}
```
````

Comment: `do.call(Sys.setenv, params)` will export all of them in one go.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Chris S, this works fine.
I share the workaround I used (create tmp file) in case someone would be interested :

````
---
output: html_document
params:
  myParam1:
    label: "Choose 1st parameter"
    value: 20
    input: slider
    min: 0
    max: 100
  myParam2:
    label: "Choose 2nd parameter"
    value: "Hello"
    input: text
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
````

**Chris solution :**

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
Sys.setenv(param1=params$myParam1)
Sys.setenv(param2=params$myParam2)
```
```{bash, echo=FALSE}
echo $param1
echo $param2
```
````

**My workaround :**

````
```{r}
param1 <- paste0("param1=\"",params$myParam1,"\"")
param2 <- paste0("param2=\"",params$myParam2,"\"")

# Write parameters in temporary file
fileConn <- file("~/params.tmp")
writeLines(c(param1,param2), fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

```{bash, echo=FALSE}
. ~/params.tmp
rm ~/params.tmp
echo $param1
echo $param2
```
````