# Cannot delete folder path when passing Rmarkdown variable into Bash

Tags: r, bash, variables, r-markdown

I'm trying to delete a folder path defined as a R variable `filepath` by using a `bash` code chunk in my Rmarkdown.

Following up from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43516681/rmarkdown-accessing-parameter-from-bash-chunk) as well as from Yihui's [example](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/061-bash-variable.md) , I passed my variable `filepath` into the `bash` chunk with the following R code chunk:

````
```{r}
Sys.setenv(FILEPATH = filepath)
```
````

While I'm able to `echo` my variable in the `bash` chunk, there was an error when I tried `rm -r` my `$FILEPATH` variable.

````
```{bash}
echo $FILEPATH
rm -r $FILEPATH
```
````

> ~/Projects/test_threshold
>
> rm: ~/Projects/test_threshold: No such file or directory

I've tried assigning my variable directly in the bash terminal for deletion and it worked.

```
deletedir=~/Projects/test_threshold
rm -r $deletedir
```

Any suggestions on what I've done wrong? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Why not just delete it from R?

````
```{r}
system("rm -r $FILEPATH")
```
````

Comment: Or just `unlink(filepath)`

Comment: `unlink` requires (nowadays?) setting the `recursive` argument to `TRUE` (see help). This may be dangerous BTW ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use an absolute path such as `/home/users/seanm/Projects/test_threshold` instead of using the tilde (which is best left as a convenience for humans.) And always always quote your variables.

Use this script to see an example of what's going wrong for you:

```
cd ~
mkdir foobar
ls ~/foobar
a="~/foobar"
echo "$a"
ls "$a"
```

You'll see this output:

```
 
~/foobar
-bash: cd: ~/foobar: No such file or directory
```